# How do I add/save records in the same row to a database? - Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

Im working with Symfony 3.4 and I would like to let the user add/edit/delete records from index (where there are displayed all records), instead of clicking on add/edit/delete buttons and opening a new page. I have been researching about this, but I cant find anything useful. I know we have to use javascript to add rows to the table, but how can I use a form into the row to perform crud options, and also modify the database. Could you please give me a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a few questions here ;-)

Recap:

You have a List of items (I'll use `tasks` in my examples)

1. You want to add/edit/delete items directly on your listing-page
2. You want to map the items to your database

There are multiple possible solutions, depending on what you use.

## JS-Frontend

You can build your list in React/VueJS/Whatever.

When you add/remove/edit a `task` you trigger an XHR/AJAX-Request to your API.
You have to implement the API endpoints and use them.

e.g.

`GET /api/tasks` => return JSON wir all tasks

`DELETE /api/tasks/7` => deletes Task with ID `7`

`POST /api/tasks`=> created a new tasks

`PUT /api/tasks/{id}` => updates task with ID. Attach JSON-Body with name, etc.

## Symfony Forms

You can also use symfony forms. You're looking for the [Collection Field-Type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html).

The `allow_add` and `allow_delete` Options will be your friends.

You can then use the objects to store the objects to the database.
e.g. using DoctrineORM or whatever you want :-)

See [Handling Form Submissions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#handling-form-submissions)

But be careful. This is not usable for large lists since it will delete all elements from the database which are not on this page.
If you want to paginate your list, this is not what you're looking for.

## My Opinion

You want to allow adding/deleting items. My guess is that you're building some Backend-Application (?).

I'd recommend a JS-Solution for the sake of simplicity.
Your API-Endpoints will be quiet simple and easy to customize.

Symfony Forms can be complex. If you want to go this direction I'd recommend you reading this [Blog-Post](https://blog.martinhujer.cz/symfony-forms-with-request-objects/) about symfony forms.

Comment: Thank you psren, I will try to make this as you suggest: JS-Frontend, I really apprecitate your help.